# Last term in a total derivative

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

If $y = f(x_1(a), x_2(a))$, $$\frac{dy}{da} = \sum_{i=1,2}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}x_i'(a) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial a}$$

How do we get that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial a}$ term? I don't understand how Chain rule works here.

Comment: The last term is there only if f=f(x1(a),x2(a),a) i.e. if there is also an explicit dependence on a and not only implicit. Otherwise it does not make sense I think

Comment: @Thomas Can you please give me an example of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too long for a comment, but maybe it helps to clarify.

Let $f(x,y,z)=xyz$. Now if $x=x(a)=a,y=y(a)=a^2,z=a$ we have $f(a)=x(a)y(a)a$. Than the chain rule in this setting reads:

$\frac{d}{da}f(x(a),y(a),a)=yzx'(a)+xzy'(a)+xy=a^3+2a^3+a^3=4a^3$

We can in this case explicitely write $f(x(a),y(a),a)=a^4$, which has a simple enough form not to require the chain rule and derivative, directly computable, is compatible with what we had using the chain rule. Note that in this case we needed to use the contribution you mentioned.

If the function was just $f(x,y)=xy$, without explicit dependence on $a$, we would not have needed the last contribution.

Does this example help to clarify?

Comment: Yes, very helpful. I assumed that that's what you meant to say but I still wanted to be clear. Apparently, I can't upvote you as I have less than 15 reputation, but thank you once again.

Comment: you are welcome